# How do you use Set::extract with a numeric key?

Tags: cakephp, set, cakephp-1.3

Given this situation:

```
$nests = array();            
for($i = 0; $i < 10; ++$i) {
   $nests[] =  array('User' => 
      array(
         'value' => array(
              0 => "zero$i",
              1 => "one$i"
          )
      )
   );
}            

debug(Set::extract('/User/value/0', $nests));
```

How do I retrieve all the zero$i? This extract above only retrieves 0 => zero0.

I know how to do this using classicExtract but I can't seem to figure this out using a straight up extract.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pr(Set::classicExtract($nests,'{n}.User.value.{0}'))
```